# Cannot type with Apple Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: 10.10, installation, bluetooth, apple

I am trying to install Ubuntu 10.10 on my iMac, but I cannot type anything in the Who Are You? stage. Is there a way to fix this. I don't own a USB keyboard, so I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If (and I say IF) you can get BlueTooth to work in a Live session on your existing computer, you should be fine. One thing that I noticed with the Apple BlueTooth keyboard is that it will never properly bind to your adapter until it is given some "name". This is something done, for example, when auto-detected on a MAC computer. I had this issue under Ubuntu 9.10, back then, and a friend of mine just tested the device on his Mac. At that time, the device was given the name of his computer, automatically. From then on, the keyboard never had any problem connecting to my Linux box. I just asked him to rename my keyboard to something else than his own name, of course. The only issue I had, and this is normal is that if I bind my keyboard, say, to my desktop, it will be unbound from my laptop. Or when it is bound to a Windows machine, instead of a Linux box.

Answer (score 1):

Go to live evaluation , wait till ubuntu loads fully!
if bluetooth window popups press always allow !!!

just make your computer's bluetooth discoverable via the ubuntu's bluetooth menu.
press add device keyboard
start pressing keys like mad
when your keyboard appears press next enter the number you see on the panel and hit enter on your mac's keyboard and you're ready.
You must deactivate bluetooth and reactivate it again to start using your keyboard, when you will start using your keyboard it will be recognised always.